# Unable to Make Get HTTP Request From Web 2 Lead Form

Tags: javascript, web2lead

I'm building an HTML page which will be later used for the web-to-lead feature of SFDC.

I'm using Javascript within to fetch the country info of the submitter.

I'm having trouble making these GET requests.
The first request is working, but I can't get the second one to work.

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Getting Clients country</title>
    
    <style>
    h1 {
        color: green;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    
    <script>
    
    // Add "https://ipinfo.io" statement
    // this will communicate with the ipify servers
    // in order to retrieve the IP address
    let myip1;
    let myip;
    $.get("https://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
            var myip=JSON.stringify(response.ip);
            var myip=JSON.parse(myip);
        }, "json")
        myip1=myip;
    $.get ("https://api.country.is/"+(myip1), function(response1){
    alert(response1.country);
        }, "json")
        
        // need help for the second get call to fetch country details
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <h1>Sample Header</h1>
        <h3>Getting Client country</h3>
    </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If some one seems to be a bit unclear about the code I can attach the sample HTML file

Comment: I am not sure why its not showing the whole code in proper format...can some one please help..I just used HTML, Code all these to make it look in proper format but when I am finally posting its taking a different format like normal paragraph which might be a bit untidy for the users who comes forward to help me.

Comment: Duplicate of [Capture Country of Lead by using JS in web to lead form in SFDC based on the IP address of the lead and update Country field of Lead record](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/406037/capture-country-of-lead-by-using-js-in-web-to-lead-form-in-sfdc-based-on-the-ip)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `jQuery` if you use `fetch`.

I've added an `onload` handler to make sure the page is rendered before trying to get the ip, but it's basically instantaneous.

```
  <!--remove jquery-->
  <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->

  window.addEventListener("load", initPage);
  
  async function initPage(){
    const myip = await getIp();
    const country = await getCountry(myip);
    console.log(country);
    //I also added an id to the country div so I could show the result.
    document.getElementById('countryheader').innerHTML = country;
  }
  
  async function getIp(){
    //had to swtich to this service because the other one is not free
    const response = await fetch("https://icanhazip.com/");
    const textData = await response.text();
    return textData;
  }
  async function getCountry(ip){
    const response = await fetch ("https://api.country.is/"+ip);
    const jsonData = await response.json();
    return jsonData.country;
  }
```